# Using ctypes with DLL - receiving incorrect return values

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm noticing a problem when using ctypes for functions that return `c_void_p`.

If I have a very simple C++ program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HLOCAL h = LocalAlloc(0, 10);
    std::cout << h;
    return 0;
}
```

I get a value of `00607498`which is 6321304. However, attempting to do the same thing with ctypes:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

win32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32.dll', use_last_error=True)
win32.LocalAlloc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_size_t]
win32.LocalAlloc.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HLOCAL
win32.LocalAlloc(0, 10)
```

I get a value of `2392687574096` which is incorrect.

Am I doing something incorrect when handling the `c_void_p` return types?

Comment: `LocalAlloc` returns an `HLOCAL`, which is a handle. How do you know that a handle is incorrect?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I was comparing it to the output of the C++ equivalent program. There appears to be a disconnect. I've set the `restype` and the resulting value is drastically different from that of the C++ one.

Comment: `LocalAlloc` isn't supposed to return the same thing every time it's called.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I don't expect it to return the same thing, but I do expect them to be relatively comparable. I am fairly certain that the value returned using `ctypes` is not a valid handle. To that end `win32.LocalFree` fails when passed that value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that LocalFree returns NULL(0) on success.  My values are similar.  Maybe you have a 32-bit compiler but 64-bit Python so the pointers look vastly different.  Did you set `.argtypes/.restype` on LocalAlloc?

```
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> import ctypes.wintypes
>>>
>>> win32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32.dll', use_last_error=True)
>>> win32.LocalAlloc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_size_t]
>>> win32.LocalAlloc.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HLOCAL
>>> h=win32.LocalAlloc(0, 10)
>>> h
2348093371568
>>> win32.LocalFree.argtypes = ctypes.wintypes.HLOCAL,
>>> win32.LocalFree.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HLOCAL
>>> win32.LocalFree(h) # None is returned for a NULL pointer
>>>
```